# Properly making navigation prop types in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a bottom tab navigator inside a drawer navigator inside a stack navigator. How do I make navigation prop types for it? I'm making them like in the docs but they don't seem to be working properly (not linking).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using the following links:

[Hiding Tabbar in screen](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens) and [Screen options with nested navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution)